# Django Trying to save my Array to the model

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have the following data coming from the

```
manager_item = request.POST.getlist(manager_type_item)
```

in my views:

```
['{"id":"1","title":"Bedroom"},{"id":"2","title":"Taps"}, {"id":"3","title":"Living Room"}']
```

Basically each one of these are `{"id":"1","title":"Bedroom"}` will need t be added into the model:

```
    index = 0
    for index, item in enumerate(json.loads(manager_item)):
        print(item['id'])
        print(item['title'])
```

But I not 100% sure the route to go. Hope someone can assist me. Still learning. I know how to save to the model I just need help with getting the data needed.

Comment: In what model? Can you share the model? What if elements with the given `id` already exist?

Comment: Model is not much of a worry here but I need to save the above list in the following table: Tags.objects.create(id=id, title=title) But the above for loop does not work I am not being able to get the data separated.

Comment: Like I said I just need the values separated, the above does not work. I will worry about the rest later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact this looks like a comma separated list of JSON blobs. We can convert this to a list as follows:

```
from json import loads as jsonload
data = jsonload('[{}]'.format(request.POST[manager_type_item]))
```

These are JSON blobs, so we can decode these with `json.loads`, and then process these, like:

```
for itm in data:
    Tag.objects.create(**itm)
```

or in case the dictionaries contain other elements that do *not* belong to the model:

```
for itm in data:
    Tag.objects.create(id=itm['id'], title=itm['title'])
```

We thus use a `map`ping to convert these JSON blobs first to there relevant *vanilla* Python objects (here dictionaries that map strings to strings), and then turn the given elements into a `Tag` (or something else).

Or in bulk:

```
Tag.objects.bulk_create([Tag(**itm) for itm in data])
```

Comment: It'd be awesome if you added a `bulk_create` example as well

Comment: @ThatBird: fixed :)

Comment: from json import loads as jsonload

tags = [
    Tag(**itm)
    for itm in map(jsonload, request.POST.getlist(manager_type_item))
]

Tag.objects.bulk_create(tags)       Just getting this error: JSONDecodeError at /blogs/update/1
Extra data: line 1 column 29 (char 28)

Comment: @Darren: what :O this is badly decoded, in fact this looks like a list with *one* string.

Comment: @Darren that probably is bad json

Comment: Haha I know. I can try send the javascript data in a better way.  This is my code in the javascript then I attach this to my hidden field.:   selected_items = [];

var items_title_{{ manager_item }} = document.getElementById('{{ manager_item }}_title_' + $(this).val()).value;

var data = {'id': '1', 'title': 'test title'};
selected_items.push(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: @Darren: nevertheless see update, but I would simply JSON stringify the entire list, not a list of JSON strings, but nevertheless, the above should probably work.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you so much up voted your answer :D great thanks man.